# Why aren't variables defined inside an include defined in the $GLOBALS array?

Tags: php, include, global

I'm trying to access a dynamically named variable that is defined inside an include file after the include is included, for example:

```
require "/path/to/my/include.php";
echo $_VariableDefinedInInclude; // outputs the variable
echo $GLOBALS["NameOfTheVariableDefinedInInclude"]; // nothing outputs?
```

Any idea why the variable is not in the $GLOBALS array? Is there a function like constant() but for standard variables that I could use to dynamically access the variable by its name?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what code you have in your include file?  Could you expand on that?

Comment: When you include a file it doesn't have anything to do with globals. It just adds the code as if it were 1 file.

Answer (score 0):

The $GLOBALS array only applies to variables set with the global keyword.  If you are including another file, it is essentially the same as the code being all in the same file.  In other words, you still have access to that variable in the same scope.  There is no need to use $GLOBALS or anything.  Additionally, if that variable is constant, you can use const (PHP 5.3) or define('KEY', $val) to define it as a constant instead.

Comment: The variable defined in the include file is dynamically named. I don't know its name but have another variable that contains its name. I could make it a constant, or an array key, but this would be inconvenient. How can I access this variable? Will this work? ${$variable_name} Or should I eval('return '.$variable_name.';');?

Comment: Code using `$$variable_name` (or the much better readable `${$variable_name}`) is often bad. Consider wrapping the data in your included file in a function returning it or if you need a global variable create a single array containing your data so you can simply access your $array instead of $$fields.

Comment: Your statement `The $GLOBALS array only applies to variables set with the global keyword` is not correct. Variables set in global scope are included in the array. Furthermore, one does not *set* (define/assign) variables with the global keyword.

Comment: The `global` keyword gives access to globals that have been defined prior. It does not set them.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the variable is dynamically-named, perhaps:

```
echo $GLOBALS[$GLOBALS["NameOfTheVariableDefinedInInclude"]];
```

will do the trick.